# how to save quill image style mvc core?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-core, quill

I'm trying to add rich text with quill
every thing works  fine but when I try to save image with style it just save the image but without any style.
this is my quill editor

```
       <div class="col-10" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
                    <div id="toolbar-container" class="w-100">
                        <span class="ql-formats">
                            <select class="ql-font"></select>
                            <select class="ql-size"></select>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ql-formats">
                            <button class="ql-bold"></button>
                            <button class="ql-italic"></button>
                            <button class="ql-underline"></button>
                            <button class="ql-strike"></button>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ql-formats">
                            <select class="ql-color"></select>
                            <select class="ql-background"></select>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ql-formats">
                            <button class="ql-script" value="sub"></button>
                            <button class="ql-script" value="super"></button>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ql-formats">
                            <button class="ql-header" value="1"></button>
                            <button class="ql-header" value="2"></button>
                            <button class="ql-blockquote"></button>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ql-formats">
                            <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
                            <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
                            <button class="ql-indent" value="-1"></button>
                            <button class="ql-indent" value="+1"></button>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ql-formats">
                            <button class="ql-direction" value="rtl"></button>
                            <select class="ql-align"></select>
                        </span>
                        <span class="ql-formats">
                            <button class="ql-link"></button>
                            <button class="ql-image add-btn"></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="editor" class="w-100" style="height: 250px;"></div>
                    <input type="hidden"asp-for="Body" name="Body"  />
                </div>
```

this how I get the value from the quill editor

```
$('#editor *').html()
```

every thing works fine except image style

Comment: You can provide some detailed code about your problem, it will be very helpful to your problem.

Comment: I add the quill  rich text and how I get its value